# DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS014544: No EJB found with interface of type 'lesson.HelloWorldLocal'

Tags: deployment, jboss, ejb

I'm trying to create a simple web app on java(ejb, jboss) but I get the following error after it is deployed:

```
13:52:53,768 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
13:52:53,828 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
13:52:53,910 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
13:52:53,919 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
13:52:54,555 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
13:52:55,014 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
13:52:55,429 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments
13:52:55,438 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015014: Re-attempting failed deployment EJBLaba1Web.war
13:52:55,468 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found EJBLaba1EJB.jar in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called EJBLaba1EJB.jar.dodeploy
13:52:55,473 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found EJBLaba1Web.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called EJBLaba1Web.war.dodeploy
13:52:55,707 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017100: Listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:4447
13:52:55,987 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-4) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080
13:52:56,063 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999
13:52:56,408 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
13:52:56,464 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "EJBLaba1Web.war"
13:52:57,754 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."EJBLaba1Web.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."EJBLaba1Web.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "EJBLaba1Web.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS014544: No EJB found with interface of type 'lesson.HelloWorldLocal' for binding servlets.TestClient/hello
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbInjectionSource.getResourceValue(EjbInjectionSource.java:88)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.addJndiBinding(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:227)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor$1.handle(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:194)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ClassDescriptionTraversal.run(ClassDescriptionTraversal.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.processClassConfigurations(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:162)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.deploy(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:155)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more

13:52:57,797 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "EJBLaba1Web.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"EJBLaba1Web.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"EJBLaba1Web.war\".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"EJBLaba1Web.war\""}}
13:52:57,818 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment EJBLaba1Web.war in 19ms
13:52:57,821 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."EJBLaba1Web.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."EJBLaba1Web.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "EJBLaba1Web.war"

13:52:57,830 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"EJBLaba1Web.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"EJBLaba1Web.war\".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"EJBLaba1Web.war\""}}}}
```

Does anyone know why I have this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is some error while deploying your .war file because of which it created the file .war.failed instead of .war.deployed. If you can look up the server log and post the error over here, it may provide pointers to solve your problem

> This is the error : 
>   No EJB found with interface of type 'lesson.HelloWorldLocal' for binding servlets.TestClient/hello